# Accordion only toggle first item in PHP function

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I have the below code stored in function.php (WordPress) and gets called using a shortcode in some pages, it basically loops through and displays the FAQ stored with each post.

However, only the first accordion item on the list can be toggled no matter which accordion item I click.

```
add_shortcode( 'qa_faqs', 'qa_faq_data' );
function qa_faq_data( $atts = array(), $content = null, $tag = '' ) {
global $post;
$html = "";
// Check rows exists.
if( have_rows('faq_repeater', $post->ID) ):
$html .= "<section class='ac-container'>";

    // Loop through rows.
    while( have_rows('faq_repeater', $post->ID) ) : the_row();

        // Load sub field value.
        $question = get_sub_field('question');
        $answer = get_sub_field('answer');
        
        $html .= "<div>";
        $html .= "<input id='faq' name='faq' type='radio'/>";
        $html .= "<label for='faq'>".$question."</label>";
        $html .= "<article>";
        $html .= "<p>".$answer."</p>";
        $html .= "</article>";
        $html .= "</div>";
        
    // End loop.
    endwhile;

$html .= "</section>";

return $html;
endif;
}
```

What am I missing?
The Accordion HTML and CSS on codepen - https://codepen.io/manabox/pen/wBQobV

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue here is that you have the same `id` (also `for` & `name` attributes) for every item in your loop

```
$html .= "<input id='faq' name='faq' type='radio'/>";
$html .= "<label for='faq'>".$question."</label>";
```

The ID in HTML must be always unique, to solve it you can do something like this below:

```
$counter = 0; //set up counter variable
...

// Loop through rows.
while( have_rows('faq_repeater', $post->ID) ) : the_row(); 
    $counter++; //increment the counter variable
    ...

$html .= "<input id='$counter' name='accordion-radio' type='radio'/>";
$html .= "<label for='$counter'>".$question."</label>";
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for pointing me to the right direction. however, I am getting an error on line 16 which I have added into my original question post (is that the right way to post/add a comment here? Can't seem to use the comment to share additional/modified codes?)

Comment: it's missing a semi colon after the counter++

Comment: True..missed that. Thank you! I am however unable to hide the content, can only click to show but can't click to hide.

Comment: can you show a working snippet ?

Comment: Just the HTML output is ok?

<section class="ac-container">
<div><input id="1" name="1" type="radio" data-com.bitwarden.browser.user-edited="yes"><label for="1">Title</label><article><p>Content</p></article></div>
</section>

Comment: please provide a working snippet like the codepen you have in your question with your HTML output and CSS

Comment: Thank you - https://codepen.io/ml39/pen/bGoYZGb

Comment: @wpbuddy sorry for the delay, and for all this comments, but I was commenting from my phone since I was out of home. The only issue is the `name`, has to be the same because it is `radio` type input and  with that it makes the desired effect. I've updated my answer

Comment: that worked! Thank you so much for your help and no need to be sorry. I am very new to this community and this is a great experience so far in terms of learning and getting help. Thank you once again.